# Not installing next-contentlayer in nextjs 14.1.0 version

Tags: next.js, blogs, contentlayer

When I am trying to install next-contentlayer in nextjs 14.1.0. It's showing error. I can't install next-contentlayer.
Can anyone suggest me how can I install it?

```
 `npm install next-contentlayer
  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
  npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! While resolving: ranadev@0.1.0
  npm ERR! Found: next@14.1.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/next
  npm ERR!   next@"14.1.0" from the root project
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer next@"^12 || ^13" from next-contentlayer@0.3.4
  npm ERR! node_modules/next-contentlayer
  npm ERR!   next-contentlayer@"*" from the root project
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) 
  dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there is a dependency conflict for next-contentlayer as it need needs next 12 or 13 and the maintainers have not updated for next 14 yet

You can try 2 things

1. Downgrade the nextjs to any of the 13 versions ( recommended )

```
npm install next@13.5.6
npm install next-contentlayer
```

2. Run with --legacy-peer-deps or --force flag.

```
npm install next-contentlayer --force
```

Answer (score 0):

They won't be updating to be used with Next 14 from what I understand.

I'd recommend using next-mdx-remote or downgrade to next 13.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).